# Convert Boolean To Custom String

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I have boolean values in my database and within a Django project I am printing them to a pdf. Its very minor but id like them to print as yes/no rather than true/false.

I know that I could use yesno if I was outputting booleans in a template:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

But I am outputting these within a function. I also know I could use an if/else statement, but was hoping for something a bit cleaner.

IE - Is there a short, clean way to convert boolean values to custom strings.

Thank you.

Comment: You can define a dict ``{True : "yes", False : "no"}``

Answer (score 11):

```
bools = ('no','yes')

value = True
print(f'The value is {bools[value]}')
```

This uses the fact that python booleans are actually stored as `int`s with `False` == 0  and `True` == 1 to index into a tuple of values.  Indexing the `bools` tuple by the boolean that you are printing then retrieves the corresponding value from the tuple.  `bools[False]` aka `bools[0]` == 'no' and `bools[True]` aka `bools[1]` == 'yes'.

Comment: Very clever solution!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> value = True 
>>> value = 'yes' if value else 'no'
>>> print(value)
'yes'
```

If you have a list of values;

```
>>> values = [True, False, False, True]
>>> values = ['yes' if val else 'no' for val in values]
>>> print(values)
['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']
```

This is a new favorite of mine, it works because in python `True == 1` and `False == 0` ;

```
# single 
value = ('no', 'yes')[value]

# multi 
values = [('no', 'yes')[val] for val in values]
```